# OpenCV reconstruct an image from small blocks of it (combine blocks)

Tags: c, opencv

In the beginning I had a picture which I've cropped into small blocks of 8 * 8 and put them in one matrix. I made some operations on them, then I encoded everything.

Now I'm trying to inverse the process and I'm blocked in the part of combining the blocks into one picture.
Are there any functions or methods in `opencv` written in `c` if possible, that could help me with my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad, please provide some code and more details describing what You want to achieve.

Comment: Create full-size output matrix of correct type and depth. For each block, extract a corresponding ROI of the output matrix (rowRange and colRange), and copy the block (copyTo) into this ROI. I C API, it's probably cvGetRows, cvGetCols, cvCopy.

Comment: @DanMašek, it's a good idea in grossomodo , but the problem is when i try to extract a corresponding ROI of the output matrix for each block i have, because they all have the same size, so basically i fall into the same ROI of the output matrix.   now i'm trying a not smart idea idea; using cvGet2D and cvSet2D to fill the full output matrix with the corresponding pixels.

Comment: Here i'm again, well i found the the solution thanks to your tips @DanMašek, i tried again with cvsetImageROI and cvCopy and cvResetImageROI on  your idea and it worked exquisitely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, i found :

```
void merging(IplImage* src,IplImage *matrice[64][64]){

IplImage *image;
image = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), matrice[0][0]->depth, matrice[0][0]->nChannels) ;
int roiSize = 8;
int i,j,k,indexW=0,indexH=0;
CvRect rctBlock;
CvScalar p;

rctBlock=cvGetImageROI(matrice[64][64]);
/* printf(" block cannaux%d\n",block->nChannels);
printf(" image cannaux%d\n",image->nChannels);
printf(" width %d\n",rctBlock.width);
printf("height %d\n",rctBlock.height); */


for(i = 0; i < image->width/roiSize; ++i) { 
for(j = 0; j < image->height/roiSize; ++j) {  
    cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(j*roiSize, i*roiSize, roiSize, roiSize));
    cvCopy(matrice[i][j],image, NULL);
    cvResetImageROI(image);          
    }
}
   // printf("H %d\n",indexH+1);
   //printf("W %d\n",indexW+1);
    cvShowImage("image",image);
    cvReleaseImage(&image);

 }
```